# Get One Page Checkout Payment Custom Form Input value

Tags: php, magento

I have

```
class My_Mymodule_Block_Server_Form extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form {
   protected function _construct()
   {
      parent::_construct();
      $this->setTemplate('mymodule/form/myinputform.phtml');            
   } 
}
```

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mymodule/form/myinputform.phtml` page with following code in it

```
<dt>
<input type="radio" class="radio" title="<?php echo $this->getmymoduleTitle(); ?>" name="payment[method]" value="SOMESTRANGEVALUE" id="p_method_mymodule" autocomplete="off">


<input type="radio" class="radio" title="<?php echo $this->getmymoduleTitle(); ?>" name="payment[method]" value="SOMESTRANGEVALUE2" id="p_method_mymodule" autocomplete="off">
```

I can see the two Inputs on the Checkout Page.
[image]
I want to get the value of this radio input in controller (Where I Post data to payment gateway).

Comment: you can see the inputs and you want to get the value? your are not being clear enough. where do you try to get the values?

Comment: In the Model which extends `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`

Comment: could you please post in your question the printed HTML?

Comment: @Fadey I Updated the Screenshot in the Question. The First two radio buttons were from the code i posted above.

Comment: Thank you, but I meant you to post your HTML code just that relevant peice of it.

Comment: Am sorry, Which html code? this radio button code? its there in Question. can you be more specific?

Comment: instead of screenshotting the form, go in your browser to view source and ge the HTML from there

Answer (score 0):

To do the same you have to create a form in the tpl file having a submit button as well.

Set the action for that to anything desired having the path of the controller i.e.

```
<form action="<?= $this->getUrl('modulename/contollername/action') ?>" id="anyForm" method="post" class="scaffold-form">
```

Now when you submit this form you will get all the field inside this in the post array of Magento in the action of the provided container.

Please make sure that the input fields are contained inside the form that you are going to add.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I need to keep the `radiobutton` value during redirection. Should I use session? or Magento already has something to keep data backend?

Comment: Can you post the code how to get the `name="payment[method]"` array and store it in registry ?

Comment: In the controller action where the data is posted fetch the data as $this->getRequest()->getPost() and then save it to registry. 

To know how to use registry you can go to the following link:  http://prattski.com/2014/09/23/using-the-magento-registry-mageregister/

Comment: When I use `name="payment[method]"` with different value for payment type radio button magento is showing a alert  "The requested Payment Method is not available"